# Как получить данные дочерней сущности OneToMany Spring

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, jpa

У меня две сущности и между ними отношения OneToMany я не понимаю как мне получить всех студентов относящихся к группе.

```
 public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long id;

    private String groupNumber;

    private int studentCount;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Student> getAllStudent(){
        return this.students;
    }
```

Везде есть пустой конструктор и геттеры с сеттерами

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "student")
   private Long id;

   private String name;


   public Student() {
   }
```

есть такой репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<Group,Long> {
}
```

Я думал должно работать что-то такое:

```
@GetMapping("/showGroup")
    public String showGroup(Model model) {
        Optional<Group> Optgroup = groupRepository.findById((long) 5);
        Iterable<Student> students = Optgroup.get().getAllStudent();

        model.addAttribute("allStudents",students);
        return "showGroup";
    }
```

Но вывод пустой. База postgres, и в ней есть три таблицы с именами как в @table и совместная. И база заполнена несколькими полями

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить в Group  fetch = FetchType.EAGER чтобы стало.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```